# Cannot Display JOptionPane When Button Is Pressed

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, joptionpane, jtextpane

So I have the following Code:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class Window extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

public static JTextPane text = new JTextPane();
public static BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
public static JButton debug = new JButton("Debug");
public static boolean isDebugPressed = false;
public static JFrame frame = new JFrame();

public Window(){
    debug.addActionListener(this);
    this.setLayout(layout);
    this.add(debug,BorderLayout.NORTH);
    this.add(text,BorderLayout.CENTER);


}

public static void main(String[] args){
    Window window = new Window();
    frame.setLayout(layout);
    frame.setSize(new Dimension(600,600));
    frame.setTitle("QuickScript Compiler");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.add(window);
    debug.setActionCommand("debug");
    if (isDebugPressed){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Output: " + text.getText().toString() , "Debugging", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
    }
}

@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (e.getActionCommand().equals("debug")){
        isDebugPressed = true;
        System.out.println("true");
    }

}
```

and when I press the debug button a box should pop up and display whatever I typed inside of the text pane, but there is nothing that shows up. How do I fix this? I have a feeling that I may have missed something very important, but I just can't figure out what it is. Thanks to anybody who can help :D

Answer (score 3):

```
//if (isDebugPressed){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Output: " + text.getText().toString() , "Debugging", JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
```

The code to display the option pane needs to be added to the ActionListener.

The variable isDebugPressed is false when the GUI is created and that statement is never executed again.

Also, because the ActionListener is only ever added to the Debug button you don't need to set an action command and check the command in the ActionListener. The source button will always be the Debug button so you can just display the option pane.

Comment: Wow thanks! I was trying to use a boolean for some reason, and I didn't even think to put that there directly. I overthought it, thanks for that answer!! @camickr

Comment: @user2449865, also don't use static variables in your class.

Comment: whats the problem with them? As I recall static variables are variables that are not destroyed when they go out of scope, and should not change. Is there a downside of using them or something? @camickr

Comment: You are describing are instance variables and that is what you should be using. Also, your instance variables should not be public. They should be private. Any method in your class can still access them. If you need to access the variables outside of your class then you should create a "getter" method. A static variable means only a single instance of a variable is created for all classes of the same type. See Swing tutorial on [Variables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) for a better description.

Comment: See also: [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).